# C# - DateTimePicker, detect up-down click events

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm re-writing the C# `DateTimePicker (nullable)` to fit my needs, but I'm stuck at detecting the up-down events from picking time `(HH:mm, DateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true)`.

I am aware that the `OnValueChanged` is fired when the either the up or down button is pressed, but I already have some handling there (move to next field automatically when a number is typed in to the DateTimePicker), and therefor I need to block the ValueChanged event when those buttons are pressed, and handle it in a different function.

I'm trying to override the WndProc function, but OnValueChanged are called before WndProc. OnKeyDown is also called after OnValueChanged.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try overriding `OnDropDown` which occurs whenever the drop down calender is requested.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm using the ShowUpDown instead of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You should not block `ValueChanged` event, when value of `DateTimePicker` is changed. And Up Down buttons are used for changing `DateTimePicker` value, thus pressing them should raise `ValueChanged` event.

Consider to change your current handling of this event.

*BTW* Why are you navigating to next field when value changed? Just assign appropriate `TabIndex` values to your controls and allow user to use `Tab` button for navigation to next field. This is a common approach for navigation.

Comment: I have to controls one with dd.MM.yyyy and another with HH:mm. After entering the days, I want the control to move to the MM part. TabIndex is for controls, not inside the DateTimePicker as I am aware of.

Comment: @user1782815 inside DateTimePicker left and right arrow keys are used for navigation

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but it is unnecessary for the user to use arrow navigation after entering one part of the date or time. 

I fixed this issue by placing a panel above the UpDown buttons, since I do not need this functionality (since the user can use arrowkeys inside the control).

Comment: Fact that user *can* use arrowkeys inside control, doesn't mean he *should* use arrowkeys. What about users, which prefer to use mouse?

Comment: Good point, seems like I'll have to create my own buttons on top (although it might seem like a stupid thing to do, I need to separate ValueChanged and the button clicks).